# Using ctypes to send an object to c++

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

I have some python code which generates a tree data structure using the `TreeNode` class below. Each node can have n-children stored withing the `children` attribute:

```
@dataclass
class TreeNode:
    type: NodeType
    # More stuff
    children: list = field(default_factory=list)
```

Once the tree is generated I want to somehow pass it (or replicate it) to some C++ code so that I can do further analysis on it. I'm trying to do this using the `ctypes` module here's my code:

```
lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(
    os.path.abspath("../path/libtest.so")
)


if __name__ == "__main__":
            tree = gen_tree(inpt)
            proto = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.py_object)
            consume_tree = proto(("consumeTree", lib))
            consume_tree(tree)
```

Here's the `consumeTree` in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Python.h>

#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
using namespace std;

void consumeTree(PyObject *obj)
{
    PyObject *printFunc, *result;

    printFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(obj, "print");
    result = PyObject_CallFunction(printFunc, NULL);

    cout << "Tree Representation: \n\n"
         << PyUnicode_AsUTF8(PyObject_Str(result)) << endl;
}
```

But I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "/home/path/test.py", line 31, in <module>
    consume_tree = proto(("consumeTree", lib))
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: /home/path/lib.so: undefined symbol: consumeTree
```

What am I doing wrong here??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

c++ mangles function names, adding info about argument types and other goodies to it. So, there is no 'consumeTree' there, but 'consumeTreexxxxx' where xxxxx is some suffix generated by the compiler.

The easiest way to work around it is to declare 'c' binding for the *consumeTree*. In other words:

```
extern "C" void consumeTree(PyObject *obj){...}
```

This will instruct compiler to generate a regular 'c' name.

Comment: Thanks this fixed the error but now I'm getting a segmentation fault error. Do you think my tree object is getting garbage collected?

Comment: This would be a different question. Try to debug it first.